# Axios to Laravel server empty $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, electron

I am using Axios in an electron app to send request to Laravel server. The server receives empty here is the server code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Requests\TimeInterval\BulkDestroyTimeIntervalRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\TimeInterval\BulkEditTimeIntervalRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\TimeInterval\CreateTimeIntervalRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\TimeInterval\DestroyTimeIntervalRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\TimeInterval\EditTimeIntervalRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\TimeInterval\ShowTimeIntervalRequest;
use Filter;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Screenshot;
use App\Models\TimeInterval;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Rules\BetweenDate;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Auth;
use Route;
use Storage;
use Validator;

class TimeIntervalController extends ItemController
{
    public function getItemClass(): string
    {
        return TimeInterval::class;
    }

    public function create(CreateTimeIntervalRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $intervalData = $request->validated();

        $timeInterval = TimeInterval::create($intervalData);

        //create screenshot
        if (isset($request->screenshot)) {
            if (!Storage::exists('uploads/screenshots/thumbs')) {
                Storage::makeDirectory('uploads/screenshots/thumbs');
            }

            $path = Filter::process(
                $this->getEventUniqueName('request.item.create'),
                $request->screenshot->store('uploads/screenshots')
            );

            Filter::process('item.create.screenshot.manual', Screenshot::createByInterval($timeInterval, $path));
        }

        if ($timeInterval->is_manual) {
            Filter::process('item.create.screenshot.manual', Screenshot::createByInterval($timeInterval));
        }

        return new JsonResponse(
            Filter::process($this->getEventUniqueName('answer.success.item.create'), [
                'interval' => $timeInterval,
            ])
        );
    }

    public function getValidationRules(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @api             {post} /time-intervals/create Create
     * @apiDescription  Create Time Interval
     *
     * @apiVersion      1.0.0
     * @apiName         Create
     * @apiGroup        Time Interval
     *
     * @apiUse          AuthHeader
     *
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_create
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_full_access
     *
     * @apiParam {Integer}  task_id           Task id
     * @apiParam {Integer}  user_id           User id
     * @apiParam {String}   start_at          Interval time start
     * @apiParam {String}   end_at            Interval time end
     *
     * @apiParam {Integer}  [activity_fill]   Activity rate as a percentage
     * @apiParam {Integer}  [mouse_fill]      Time spent using the mouse as a percentage
     * @apiParam {Integer}  [keyboard_fill]   Time spent using the keyboard as a percentage
     *
     * @apiParamExample {json} Request Example
     * {
     *   "task_id": 1,
     *   "user_id": 1,
     *   "start_at": "2013-04-12T16:40:00-04:00",
     *   "end_at": "2013-04-12T16:40:00-04:00"
     * }
     *
     * @apiSuccess {Object}   interval  Interval
     *
     * @apiUse          TimeIntervalObject
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Response Example
     *  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     *  {
     *    "interval": {
     *      "id": 2251,
     *      "task_id": 1,
     *      "start_at": "2013-04-12 20:40:00",
     *      "end_at": "2013-04-12 20:40:00",
     *      "is_manual": true,
     *      "created_at": "2018-10-01 03:20:59",
     *      "updated_at": "2018-10-01 03:20:59",
     *      "activity_fill": 0,
     *      "mouse_fill": 0,
     *      "keyboard_fill": 0,
     *      "user_id": 1
     *    }
     *  }
     *
     * @apiUse         400Error
     * @apiUse         ValidationError
     * @apiUse         UnauthorizedError
     * @apiUse         ForbiddenError
     */

    public function getEventUniqueNamePart(): string
    {
        return 'timeinterval';
    }

    /**
     * @apiDeprecated   since 1.0.0
     * @api             {post} /time-intervals/bulk-create Bulk Create
     * @apiDescription  Create Time Intervals
     *
     * @apiVersion      1.0.0
     * @apiName         Bulk Create
     * @apiGroup        Time Interval
     */

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function index(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $filters = $request->all();
        $request->get('project_id') ? $filters['task.project_id'] = $request->get('project_id') : false;

        $baseQuery = $this->applyQueryFilter(
            $this->getQuery(),
            $filters ?: []
        );

        $itemsQuery = Filter::process(
            $this->getEventUniqueName('answer.success.item.list.query.prepare'),
            $baseQuery
        );

        return new JsonResponse(
            Filter::process(
                $this->getEventUniqueName('answer.success.item.list.result'),
                $itemsQuery->get()
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @api             {post} /time-intervals/list List
     * @apiDescription  Get list of Time Intervals
     *
     * @apiVersion      1.0.0
     * @apiName         List
     * @apiGroup        Time Interval
     *
     * @apiUse          AuthHeader
     *
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_list
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_full_access
     *
     * @apiUse          TimeIntervalParams
     * @apiUse          TimeIntervalObject
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Response Example
     *  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     *  [
     *    {
     *      "id": 1,
     *      "task_id": 1,
     *      "start_at": "2006-06-20 15:54:40",
     *      "end_at": "2006-06-20 15:59:38",
     *      "created_at": "2018-10-15 05:54:39",
     *      "updated_at": "2018-10-15 05:54:39",
     *      "deleted_at": null,
     *      "activity_fill": 42,
     *      "mouse_fill": 43,
     *      "keyboard_fill": 43,
     *      "user_id":1
     *    }
     *  ]
     *
     * @apiUse         400Error
     * @apiUse         UnauthorizedError
     * @apiUse         ForbiddenError
     */

    /**
     * @api             {post} /time-intervals/show Show
     * @apiDescription  Show Time Interval
     *
     * @apiVersion      1.0.0
     * @apiName         Show
     * @apiGroup        Time Interval
     *
     * @apiUse          AuthHeader
     *
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_show
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_full_access
     *
     * @apiParam {Integer}  id     Time Interval id
     *
     * @apiUse          TimeIntervalParams
     *
     * @apiParamExample {json} Request Example
     * {
     *   "id": 1
     * }
     *
     * @apiUse          TimeIntervalObject
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Response Example
     * {
     *   "id": 1,
     *   "task_id": 1,
     *   "start_at": "2006-05-31 16:15:09",
     *   "end_at": "2006-05-31 16:20:07",
     *   "created_at": "2018-09-25 06:15:08",
     *   "updated_at": "2018-09-25 06:15:08",
     *   "deleted_at": null,
     *   "activity_fill": 42,
     *   "mouse_fill": 43,
     *   "keyboard_fill": 43,
     *   "user_id": 1
     * }
     *
     * @apiUse         400Error
     * @apiUse         UnauthorizedError
     * @apiUse         ItemNotFoundError
     * @apiUse         ForbiddenError
     * @apiUse         ValidationError
     */
    public function show(ShowTimeIntervalRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        return $this->_show($request);
    }

    /**
     * @api             {post} /time-intervals/edit Edit
     * @apiDescription  Edit Time Interval
     *
     * @apiVersion      1.0.0
     * @apiName         Edit
     * @apiGroup        Time Interval
     *
     * @apiUse          AuthHeader
     *
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_edit
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_full_access
     *
     * @apiParam {Integer}  id           Time Interval id
     *
     * @apiUse          TimeIntervalParams
     *
     * @apiSuccess {Object}   res      TimeInterval
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Response Example
     *  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     *  {
     *    "res": {
     *      "id":1,
     *      "task_id":1,
     *      "start_at":"2018-10-03 10:00:00",
     *      "end_at":"2018-10-03 10:00:00",
     *      "created_at":"2018-10-15 05:50:39",
     *      "updated_at":"2018-10-15 05:50:43",
     *      "deleted_at":null,
     *      "activity_fill": 42,
     *      "mouse_fill": 43,
     *      "keyboard_fill": 43,
     *      "user_id":1
     *    }
     *  }
     *
     * @apiUse         400Error
     * @apiUse         ValidationError
     * @apiUse         UnauthorizedError
     * @apiUse         ItemNotFoundError
     */

    /**
     * @api             {post} /time-intervals/bulk-edit Bulk Edit
     * @apiDescription  Multiple Edit TimeInterval to assign tasks to them
     *
     * @apiVersion      1.0.0
     * @apiName         Bulk Edit
     * @apiGroup        Time Interval
     *
     * @apiUse          AuthHeader
     *
     * @apiParam {Object[]}  intervals          Time Intervals to edit
     * @apiParam {Integer}   intervals.id       Time Interval ID
     * @apiParam {Integer}   intervals.task_id  Task ID
     *
     * @apiParamExample {json} Request Example
     * {
     *   "intervals": [
     *     {
     *       "id": 12,
     *       "task_id": 12
     *     },
     *     {
     *       "id": 13,
     *       "task_id": 16
     *     }
     *   ]
     * }
     *
     * @apiSuccess {String}     message    Message from server
     * @apiSuccess {Integer[]}  updated    Updated intervals
     * @apiSuccess {Integer[]}  not_found  Not found intervals
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Response Example
     *  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     *  {
     *    "message": "Intervals successfully updated",
     *    "updated": [12, 123, 45],
     *  }
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Not all intervals updated Response Example
     *  HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
     *  {
     *    "message": "Some intervals have not been updated",
     *    "updated": [12, 123, 45],
     *    "not_found": [154, 77, 66]
     *  }
     *
     * @apiUse          400Error
     * @apiUse          ValidationError
     * @apiUse          UnauthorizedError
     * @apiUse          ForbiddenError
     */

    /**
     * @param EditTimeIntervalRequest $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function edit(EditTimeIntervalRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $requestData = Filter::process(
            $this->getEventUniqueName('request.item.edit'),
            $request->all()
        );

        $validationRules = $this->getValidationRules();
        $validationRules['id'] = 'required|integer';

        $validator = Validator::make(
            $requestData,
            Filter::process(
                $this->getEventUniqueName('validation.item.edit'),
                $validationRules
            )
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                Filter::process($this->getEventUniqueName('answer.error.item.edit'), [
                    'error_type' => 'validation',
                    'message' => 'Validation error',
                    'info' => $validator->errors()
                ]),
                400
            );
        }

        //create time interval
        $requestData['start_at'] = (new Carbon($requestData['start_at']))->setTimezone('UTC')->toDateTimeString();
        $requestData['end_at'] = (new Carbon($requestData['end_at']))->setTimezone('UTC')->toDateTimeString();

        /** @var Builder $itemsQuery */
        $itemsQuery = Filter::process(
            $this->getEventUniqueName('answer.success.item.query.prepare'),
            $this->applyQueryFilter(
                $this->getQuery()
            )
        );

        /** @var Model $item */
        $item = collect($itemsQuery->get())->first(static function ($val, $key) use ($request) {
            return $val['id'] === $request->get('id');
        });

        if (!$item) {
            return new JsonResponse(
                Filter::process($this->getEventUniqueName('answer.error.item.edit'), [
                    'error_type' => 'query.item_not_found',
                    'message' => 'Item not found',
                ]),
                404
            );
        }

        $item->fill($this->filterRequestData($requestData));
        $item = Filter::process($this->getEventUniqueName('item.edit'), $item);
        $item->save();

        return new JsonResponse(
            Filter::process($this->getEventUniqueName('answer.success.item.edit'), [
                'res' => $item,
            ])
        );
    }

    /**
     * @api             {post} /users/remove Destroy
     * @apiDescription  Destroy Time Interval
     *
     * @apiVersion      1.0.0
     * @apiName         Destroy
     * @apiGroup        Time Interval
     *
     * @apiUse          AuthHeader
     *
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_remove
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_full_access
     *
     * @apiParam {Integer}  id  ID of the target interval
     *
     * @apiParamExample {json} Request Example
     * {
     *   "id": 1
     * }
     *
     * @apiSuccess {String}   message  Destroy status
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Response Example
     *  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     *  {
     *    "message": "Item has been removed"
     *  }
     *
     * @apiUse          400Error
     * @apiUse          ValidationError
     * @apiUse          ForbiddenError
     * @apiUse          UnauthorizedError
     */

    /**
     * @api             {get,post} /time-intervals/count Count
     * @apiDescription  Count Time Intervals
     *
     * @apiVersion      1.0.0
     * @apiName         Count
     * @apiGroup        Time Interval
     *
     * @apiUse          AuthHeader
     *
     * @apiSuccess {String}   total    Amount of users that we have
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Response Example
     *  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     *  {
     *    "total": 2
     *  }
     *
     * @apiUse          400Error
     * @apiUse          ForbiddenError
     * @apiUse          UnauthorizedError
     */
    public function count(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        return $this->_count($request);
    }

    /**
     * @api            {post} /time-intervals/bulk-remove Bulk Destroy
     * @apiDescription Multiple Destroy TimeInterval
     *
     * @apiVersion     1.0.0
     * @apiName        Bulk Destroy
     * @apiGroup       Time Interval
     *
     * @apiUse         AuthHeader
     *
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_bulk_remove
     * @apiPermission   time_intervals_full_access
     *
     * @apiParam {Integer[]}  intervals  Intervals ID to delete
     *
     * @apiParamExample {json} Request Example
     * {
     *   "intervals": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
     * }
     *
     * @apiSuccess {String}     message    Message from server
     * @apiSuccess {Integer[]}  removed    Removed intervals
     * @apiSuccess {Integer[]}  not_found  Not found intervals
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Response Example
     *  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     *  {
     *    "message": "Intervals successfully removed",
     *    "removed": [12, 123, 45],
     *  }
     *
     * @apiSuccessExample {json} Not all intervals removed Response Example
     *  HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
     *  {
     *    "message": "Some intervals have not been removed",
     *    "removed": [12, 123, 45],
     *    "not_found": [154, 77, 66]
     *  }
     *
     * @apiUse         400Error
     * @apiUse         ValidationError
     * @apiUse         ForbiddenError
     * @apiUse         UnauthorizedError
     */
    public function destroy(DestroyTimeIntervalRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        return $this->_destroy($request);
    }

    /**
     * @param BulkEditTimeIntervalRequest $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function bulkEdit(BulkEditTimeIntervalRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $intervalsData = collect($request->validated()['intervals']);

        /** @var Builder $itemsQuery */
        $itemsQuery = Filter::process(
            $this->getEventUniqueName('answer.success.item.query.prepare'),
            $this->applyQueryFilter($this->getQuery(), ['id' => ['in', $intervalsData->pluck('id')->toArray()]])
        );

        $itemsQuery->each(static function (Model $item) use ($intervalsData) {
            $item->update(Arr::only($intervalsData->where('id', $item->id)->first(), 'task_id'));
        });

        $responseData = [
            'message' => 'Intervals successfully updated',
        ];

        return new JsonResponse(
            Filter::process($this->getEventUniqueName('answer.success.item.edit'), $responseData),
            200
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param BulkDestroyTimeIntervalRequest $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function bulkDestroy(BulkDestroyTimeIntervalRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $intervalIds = $request->validated()['intervals'];

        /** @var Builder $itemsQuery */
        $itemsQuery = Filter::process(
            $this->getEventUniqueName('answer.success.item.query.prepare'),
            $this->applyQueryFilter($this->getQuery(), ['id' => ['in', $intervalIds]])
        );

        // to cascade screenshots soft deleting
        foreach ($itemsQuery->getModels() as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }

        $responseData = [
            'message' => 'Intervals successfully removed',
        ];

        return new JsonResponse(
            Filter::process($this->getEventUniqueName('answer.success.item.remove'), $responseData),
            200
        );
    }
}
```

here is the CreateTimeIntervalRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\TimeInterval;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Rules\TimeIntervalDoesNotExist;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateTimeIntervalRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if user authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'task_id' => 'required|exists:tasks,id',
            'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
            'start_at' => 'required|date|bail|before:end_at',
            'end_at' => [
                'required',
                'date',
                'bail',
                'after:start_at',
                new TimeIntervalDoesNotExist(
                    User::find($this->user_id),
                    Carbon::parse($this->start_at),
                    Carbon::parse($this->end_at)
                ),
            ],
            'activity_fill' => 'int|between:0,100',
            'mouse_fill' => 'int|between:0,100',
            'keyboard_fill' => 'int|between:0,100',
            'is_manual' => 'bool',
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is the Axios code:

```
async createWithScreenshot(interval, screenshot) {

    if (typeof interval !== 'object')
      throw new TypeError(`Interval DTO must be an object, but ${typeof intervalId} is given`);

    if (!Buffer.isBuffer(screenshot))
      throw new TypeError(`Screenshot must be a Buffer, but ${typeof screenshot} is given`);

    const reqData = new FormData();
    const querystring = require('querystring');
    reqData.append('task_id', interval.taskId);
    reqData.append('user_id', interval.userId);
    reqData.append('start_at', interval.start.toISOString());
    reqData.append('end_at', interval.end.toISOString());
    reqData.append('activity_fill', interval.systemActivity);
    reqData.append('screenshot', screenshot, { filename: 'screenshot.jpeg' });
    reqData.append("_method", "put");

    if (interval.keyboardActivity)
      reqData.append('keyboard_fill', interval.keyboardActivity);

    if (interval.mouseActivity)
      reqData.append('mouse_fill', interval.mouseActivity);
      console.log(reqData);
    const res = await this.$.post('time-intervals/create', reqData, { headers: reqData.getHeaders(), });
    console.log(res);
    if (!res.success) {

      if (res.isNetworkError)
        throw new this.$.NetworkError(res);

      throw new this.$.ApiError(
        res.error.response.status,
        res.error.response.data.error_type || 'unknown',
        res.error.response.data.message || 'Unknown message',
      );

    }

    return CattrIntervals.represent(res.response.data.interval);

  }

  /**
   * Removes interval
   * @async
   * @param {Number} intervalId Identifier of interval being removed
   * @returns {Promise<Boolean>}
   */
  async remove(intervalId) {

    if (typeof intervalId !== 'number')
      throw new TypeError(`Interval ID  must be a Number, but ${typeof intervalId} is given`);

    const res = await this.$.post('time-intervals/remove', { id: intervalId });
    if (!res.success) {

      if (res.isNetworkError)
        throw new this.$.NetworkError(res);

      throw new this.$.ApiError(
        res.error.response.status,
        res.error.response.data.error_type || 'unknown',
        res.error.response.data.message || 'Unknown message',
      );

    }

    return true;

  }

}
```

Here is the post function for Axios

async post(url, body, opts) {

```
if (typeof url !== 'string')
  throw new TypeError(`URL parameter must be a string, but ${typeof url} given`);

if (typeof body !== 'object')
  throw new TypeError(`Body must be an object (for JSON or FormData), but ${typeof body} given`);

const headers = {};

if (opts && typeof opts.headers === 'object')
  Object.assign(headers, opts.headers);

if (opts && opts.isFormData === true)
  headers['Content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';

if (opts && opts.method && [ 'post', 'put', 'patch' ].indexOf(opts.method) === -1)
  throw new TypeError(`Unsupported request method: ${opts.method}`);

if (!opts || !opts.noAuth) {

  const token = await this.providers.token.get();

  // Renewing token if it isn't available in provider
  if (!token) {

    if (opts && opts.noRelogin) {

      return {
        success: false,
        isNetworkError: false,
        error: new this.CredentialsError(401, 'authorization.unauthorized', 'Token provider returned nothing, but relogin is disabled')
      };

    }

    if (!await this.reloginAutomatically()) {

      return {
        success: false,
        isNetworkError: false,
        error: new this.CredentialsError(401, 'authorization.unauthorized', 'Token provider returned nothing, and relogin is failed')
      };

    }

  }

  headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${(await this.providers.token.get()).token}`;

}
 console.log(headers);
// Making request
try {

  const res = await this.axios({
    url,
    headers,
    data: body,
    method: (opts && opts.method) ? opts.method : 'post',
  });
 

  return {
    success: true,
    response: res
  };


} catch (err) {
  

  // Pass error if autentication disabled
  if (opts && opts.noAuth)
    return { success: false, isNetworkError: err.response ? !Number.isNaN(err.response.status) : true, error: err };

  // Return networking error
  if (!err.response)
    return { success: false, isNetworkError: true, error: err };

  // Pass error if it isn't related to the authentication token
  if (
    err.response.status !== 401 ||
    (err.response.data.error_type !== 'authorization.unauthorized' && err.response.data.error_type !== 'authorization.token_expired')
  )
    return { success: false, isNetworkError: false, error: err };

  // Pass error if automatical relogin is disabled
  if (opts && opts.noRelogin)
    return { success: false, isNetworkError: false, error: err };

  // Try to relogin automatically, pass error if failed
  if (!await this.reloginAutomatically())
    return { success: false, isNetworkError: false, error: err };


  // Say hi to recursion!
  return this.post(url, body, Object.assign(opts || {}, { noRelogin: true }));

}
```

}

It gives validation error, but works perfect in postman.

Here is the postman Axios code generated

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('task_id', '1');
data.append('user_id', '1');
data.append('start_at', '2021-05-06T08:55:05.971Z');
data.append('end_at', '2021-05-07T09:23:05.261Z');
data.append('activity_fill', '84');
data.append('screenshot', fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file'));

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://work.digifrizz.net/public/time-intervals/create',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC93b3JrLmRpZ2lmcml6ei5uZXRcL3B1YmxpY1wvYXV0aFwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2MjI0NTYwNTAsImV4cCI6MTY1Mzk5MjA1MCwibmJmIjoxNjIyNDU2MDUwLCJqdGkiOiIzbDYxV3lHWXNiZ1ZPS0c1Iiwic3ViIjoxLCJwcnYiOiIyM2JkNWM4OTQ5ZjYwMGFkYjM5ZTcwMWM0MDA4NzJkYjdhNTk3NmY3Iiwibm9uY2UiOjB9.5iaN2flb-sBt3zxTa0hoUdz4pjfj73TcKGQcm5bZEbc', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Please help

Comment: You really think we need all this code?

Comment: Its for if you need to see some code

Answer (score 0):

Does the postman version of the code works?

If you have access to the server code, put the following lines in the code to debug the body contents of the request so you can have better insights of what is reaching to the server:

- dd($request->getContent());
- dd($request->getBody());
- dd($request->all());

If you see that the request data is reaching to the server at least as raw text then maybe the issue comes from the content type that you are sending to the server. You may try to add the content-type: application/json header to see if this helps.

Comment: Postman version of the code doesn't work but when I am doing through postman it works